# Memory Usage Issues with CV2.imread()

Tags: python, opencv

I have built a faster r-cnn model and am in the process of labeling images with a bunch of bounding boxes. My issue is that the python kernel eventually crashes while labeling the first ~3000 out of 70,000 images. I have narrowed down the issue to image = cv2.imread().Regardless of using del image or image = None, the excessive memory usage persists. Is there a none memory leak issue with the CV2 library? I am using version 3.3. Is there anyway to clear memory? Thanks.

```
def SaveFigureAsImage(fileName,fig=None,**kwargs):
    ''' Save a Matplotlib figure as an image without borders or frames.
       Args:
            fileName (str): String that ends in .png etc.

            fig (Matplotlib figure instance): figure you want to save as the image
        Keyword Args:
            orig_size (tuple): width, height of the original image used to maintain 
            aspect ratio.
    '''
    a=fig.gca()
    a.set_frame_on(False)
    a.set_xticks([]); a.set_yticks([])
    plt.axis('off')
    fig.savefig(fileName, transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight', \
                        pad_inches=0)

#classes
classes = {
redacted
}

#load model
image_input = keras.layers.Input((None, None, 3))
model = keras_retinanet.models.ResNet50RetinaNet(image_input, num_classes=len(classes), weights='imagenet')
model.load_weights('snapshots/resnet50_model_1_6.h5')

test_image_data_generator = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
#possibely resize the image
test_generator = PascalVocIterator(
    '../',
    'test',
    test_image_data_generator,
    classes=classes
)

#stats
frequency = {} 

ef read_image_bgr(path):
    image = np.asarray(PIL.Image.open(path).convert('RGB'))
    return image[:, :, ::-1].copy()


def preprocess_image(x):
    # mostly identical to "https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py"
    # except for converting RGB -> BGR since we assume BGR already
    x = x.astype(keras.backend.floatx())
    if keras.backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        if x.ndim == 3:
            x[0, :, :] -= 103.939
            x[1, :, :] -= 116.779
            x[2, :, :] -= 123.68
        else:
            x[:, 0, :, :] -= 103.939
            x[:, 1, :, :] -= 116.779
            x[:, 2, :, :] -= 123.68
    else:
        x[..., 0] -= 103.939
        x[..., 1] -= 116.779
        x[..., 2] -= 123.68

    return x


def random_transform(
    image,
    boxes,
    image_data_generator,
    seed=None
):
    if seed is None:
        seed = np.random.randint(10000)

    image = image_data_generator.random_transform(image, seed=seed)

    # set fill mode so that masks are not enlarged
    fill_mode = image_data_generator.fill_mode
    image_data_generator.fill_mode = 'constant'

    for index in range(boxes.shape[0]):
        # generate box mask and randomly transform it
        mask = np.zeros_like(image, dtype=np.uint8)
        b = boxes[index, :4].astype(int)

        assert(b[0] < b[2] and b[1] < b[3]), 'Annotations contain invalid box: {}'.format(b)
        assert(b[2] <= image.shape[1] and b[3] <= image.shape[0]), 'Annotation ({}) is outside of image shape ({}).'.format(b, image.shape)

        mask[b[1]:b[3], b[0]:b[2], :] = 255
        mask = image_data_generator.random_transform(mask, seed=seed)[..., 0]
        mask = mask.copy()  # to force contiguous arrays

        # find bounding box again in augmented image
        [i, j] = np.where(mask == 255)
        boxes[index, 0] = float(min(j))
        boxes[index, 1] = float(min(i))
        boxes[index, 2] = float(max(j)) + 1  # set box to an open interval [min, max)
        boxes[index, 3] = float(max(i)) + 1  # set box to an open interval [min, max)

    # restore fill_mode
    image_data_generator.fill_mode = fill_mode

    return image, boxes


def resize_image(img, min_side=600, max_side=1024):
    (rows, cols, _) = img.shape

    smallest_side = min(rows, cols)

    # rescale the image so the smallest side is min_side
    scale = min_side / smallest_side

    # check if the largest side is now greater than max_side, which can happen
    # when images have a large aspect ratio
    largest_side = max(rows, cols)
    if largest_side * scale > max_side:
        scale = max_side / largest_side

    # resize the image with the computed scale
    img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=scale, fy=scale)

    return img, scale

def run(beg):
    gc.enable()
    images_path = glob.glob('../1brower-167136992/data/167136992/SESI/SESI_files/19/*.jpg')
    
    count = -1 
    for p in images_path:
        count += 1
        if count >= beg and count - beg < 2000:
            #image = cv2.imread(p) #this is the memory leak
            image = np.array(Image.open(p))
            image_copy = image.copy()
            
            #preprocess image
            image_copy = preprocess_image(image_copy)
            image, scale = resize_image(image, 600, 600)
            image_copy, scale = resize_image(image_copy, 600, 600)
            
            name = p.split('/')[7]
            name = name.split('.jpg')[0]
            start = time.time()
            _, _, detections = model.predict_on_batch(np.expand_dims(image_copy, axis=0))
            print("processing time: ", time.time() - start)

            im = image.copy()
            predicted_labels = np.argmax(detections[0, :, 4:], axis=1)
            scores = np.max(detections[0, :, 4:], axis=1)

            for idx, (label, score) in enumerate(zip(predicted_labels, scores)):
                #print(label, score)
                if score < 0.25: #change the 0.5 cutoff to a lower number
                    continue
                b = detections[0, idx, :4].astype(int)
                caption = "{} {:.3f}".format(test_generator.labels[label], score)
                if label == 0:
                    cv2.rectangle(im, (b[0], b[1]), (b[2], b[3]), (255, 0, 0), 3)
                    if "redacted" not in frequency:
                        frequency["redacted"] = 1
                    else:
                        frequency["redacted"] += 1
                elif label == 2:
                    cv2.rectangle(im, (b[0], b[1]), (b[2], b[3]), (0, 0, 255), 3)
                    if "redacted" not in frequency:
                        frequency["redacted"] = 1
                    else:
                        frequency["redacted"] += 1
                elif label == 3:
                    cv2.rectangle(im, (b[0], b[1]), (b[2], b[3]), (0, 120, 120), 3)
                    if "redacted" not in frequency:
                        frequency["redacted"] = 1
                    else:
                        frequency["redacted"] += 1
                elif label == 4:
                    cv2.rectangle(im, (b[0], b[1]), (b[2], b[3]), (0, 120, 120), 3)
                    if "pocks" not in frequency:
                        frequency["redacted"] = 1
                    else:
                        frequency["redacted"] += 1
                else:
                    cv2.rectangle(im, (b[0], b[1]), (b[2], b[3]), (0, 255, 0), 3)
                    if "redacted" not in frequency:
                        frequency["redacted"] = 1
                    else:
                        frequency["redacted"] += 1
                cv2.putText(im, caption, (b[0], b[1] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.5, (0, 0, 0), 3)
                cv2.putText(im, caption, (b[0], b[1] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)
            plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
            plt.axis('off')
            plt.imshow(im)
            print(name)
            SaveFigureAsImage('../processed_data/' + name, plt.gcf() )
            plt.close("all")
            print("----------------------------")
            #print(gc.collect())
```

Comment: does not your `image_batch` simply grow continuously without releasing any of its contents?

Comment: I set image_batch = [] within the for loop

Comment: ok, that's not in the code you show..

Comment: sorry. I just have some confidential code I have to redact

Comment: that's fine, have you tried using PIL instead of cv2? also can you explain what you have done to narrow down the memory leak so we don't have redundant suggestions.

Comment: If this provides more clarity, if I put bi > 2000 in the if statement, I get the same excessive memory usage before bi is greater than 2000. So it appears the problem is confined to the code between the for loop and the if statement.

Comment: how do you mean for your last 5 lines to be indented? atm they seem to be out of the loop...

Comment: I just edited the image to show the image_batch = [] is within the if statement. The code I'm referring to is between for p in images_path: and if bi % 100 == 0

Comment: well, I can't seem to find what would cause that sort of issue given the code you've shown. Have you tried using the actual [Memory profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler)?

Comment: Did you mis-indent the example when pasting it? If not, what's the point of `bi` (and the `if` that tests it) when the only time you modify it is at the end of the program?

Comment: i cannot be of any help regarding your question, but moving from `cv2` to `skimage` has greatly improved my experience of handling images.

Comment: You're still missing relevant code. Please provide a [minimal, *complete* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue. Create a new file, and delete all irrelevant lines to your issue, making sure the code you post is the exact minimal amount of code to reproduce the issue. Your code isn't updating `bi` as it stands, for e.g.. How is anyone supposed to know the problem when the code doesn't even run on its own? And how do you know `imread()` is the leak, did you use a profiler?

Comment: Going to profile it. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem - discovered via memory_profiler